# Do I have to transfer Customer's Information manually from My Code to google Checkout?

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

Is anyone has idea about in Google Checkout, How orders with Customers/Buyers information passed from my .net Code ?

We can Pass Orders to the Google Checkout by this link. But I want to know about How Customers/Buyers information send to my Google Checkout Account with the particular order also.

Thanks & Regards,
   Nitin Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a programmatic way to get customer and order information. For that you use the Checkout Notification API:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html